# Unable to resolve the promise and update data in Node.js App

Tags: node.js, express, axios

Hi I have a router defined like this in Node.js based on express which use async call :

```
const service = new YoutubeService();
router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  const trends = await service.getTrendingVideos();
  console.log(trends);
  res.render('youtube/index', {
    title: config.title,
    videos: trends
  });
});
```

My service file looks like this :

```
export class YoutubeService {
  getTrendingVideos() {
    var params = {
      part: 'snippet',
      chart: 'mostPopular',
      regionCode: 'US', // should be replaced with country code from countryList
      maxResults: '24',
      key: config.youtubeApi.key
    };

    var result = [];

    return axios.get('/', {params}).then(function(res){
      result = res.data.items;
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = {
          id: result[i].id,
          title: result[i].snippet.title,
          thumbnail: result[i].snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
          publishedAt: moment(result[i].snippet.publishedAt).fromNow()
        };
        result[i] = YoutubeService.getVideoDetails(result[i]);
      }
      return result;
    });
  }

  static getVideoDetails(video) {
    var params = {
      part: 'statistics',
      id: video.id,
      key: config.youtubeApi.key
    };

    return axios.get('/', {params}).then(function(res) {
      var result = res.data;

      video.viewCount = result['items'][0].statistics.viewCount;
      video.likeCount = result['items'][0].statistics.likeCount;
      return video;
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that first while I do console on trends it always prints `<promise> ...` like this and it's not updating data also just showing blank records in html.

When I am doing console.log inside axios get method it's printing the data. Means data is coming but not updating to my async function.

Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just adding promises to an array, and simply returning that array, which is why you're getting that console.log output as you currently are.
You're not first resolving each promise inside your loop, but instead simply returning the handle to each un-resolved promise.  You need to either `await` inside each iteration of the loop (bad practice...), or resolve your array of promises with `Promise.all`

Try resolving all of your results with a `Promise.all`

```
return axios.get('/', {params}).then(function(res){
  result = res.data.items;
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = {
      id: result[i].id,
      title: result[i].snippet.title,
      thumbnail: result[i].snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
      publishedAt: moment(result[i].snippet.publishedAt).fromNow()
    };
    result[i] = YoutubeService.getVideoDetails(result[i]);
  }
  return Promise.all(result); // <--- wrap this in a Promise.all.  It will resolve all promises in your array, concurrently.
});
```